# android - Firebase Notification Push Notification getSubText

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use this class to manage notification into my android app

```
public class NotificationMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        nb.setContentTitle(title);
        nb.setContentText(message);
        nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconanotifica);
        nb.setAutoCancel(true);
        nb.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        nb.setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

        nb.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, nb.build());
    }
}
```

Into the NotificationComapt.Builder, there is a method called: setSubText() that I want to use.
So, how do I get the "remoteMessage.getNotification().getSubText()"?

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationCompat.Builder.setSubText()` will provide some additional line of text in the Notification template per [Android NotificationCompat reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html). If the device can't support large-format notification, this has no effect.

`remoteMessage.getNotification()` will get the [notification payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) of the message that you've sent either from the Firebase Notification console or your app server with Firebase Cloud Messaging implementation.

If you'd like to add additional data parameters in your notification message, you can do it using the following options:

1. In the Firebase Notification console, add a Custom data key-value pair in the Advanced options section.
2. If you're using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), then you can send [messages with both notification and data payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads).

Use `remoteMessage.getData()` to get the data payload of the message in the client app and `get()` method to retrieve a specific value, then use it as a sub text in your Notification.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, It works. But I send notification using an android app and this is managed by a php file. Only if I send the notifcation from the database I see the subText, but not if I send from the application. Can you help?

Comment: Hey @Simone, could you please expand more the issue? If it's a separate one from the original, then update your question or just accept my answer and create a new thread.

Comment: No it isn't the solution that I want to follow. I need to send this notification from an android app and set the subtext